# What's the relation of workspace and database users in Oracle Express?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have created a workspace with APEX, but the password is invalid now.

Then I logged in to the workspace and changed the password. However, the other password for login is not changed.

I am very confused with all these terms in oracle.

I have `database username`, `workspace username`, `database password`, `workspace password`. Also there is a user manager in the workspace, and these users are different from the other two mentioned. Some of the users can be seen in `all_users` table, some cannot.

What's the relation between all these kinds of users, and where does this information stored? I have read some material of Oracle, but none mentioned these basic terms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is confusing because there are two different (though complimentary) technologies being used here:

1) **Oracle Database Server** has the concept of database "users" which you can see by querying `dba_users` and `all_users` - these are owners of database objects and each automatically gets a schema of the same name. Each of these database users has a password, managed by the database. In the old days we used to provision a separate database user for each end user; nowadays we don't generally. These users are stored in the database data dictionary and are manipulated only using database commands such as `CREATE USER` and `ALTER USER`.

2) **Oracle Application Express** has the concept of "workspaces", each of which may have one or more "users". These users can be ordinary end users, developers or Apex administrators. Each of these users has a password, managed by Apex. These are not related to schemas on the database. These users are stored in the Apex data dictionary, and are manipulated using the Apex admin interface, or via calls to the Apex API (in PL/SQL).

Each apex Workspace is associated with a database schema (= database user) which holds the database objects (e.g. tables, views, etc) needed by the workspace. (Note: a workspace can be associated with more than one database schema).

To make things more confusing, in the default version of Apex that is pre-installed in OracleXE (the free version of the database), the Apex user SYSTEM has the same password as the database SYSTEM user.

By default, Apex applications use the Apex authentication scheme which authenticates users against the Apex data dictionary (as per (2) above). You can, however, use alternative authentication schemes which authenticate users against other repositories (such as LDAP, SSO, or custom schemes).

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you very much. The worst thing is that it uses same password at first, and then turns out to be totally different things.

Comment: Don't you mean INTERNAL workspace? or does system also apply?

Comment: I have a question please regarding application users or database users , I want to create application is it possible to create database user for each user instead of application user why because for the database users you can manage its profile and control login logout and logout after idle time and manage the user or in apex application users I can manage these profiles also , before in oracle forms I created an application users but all application users login at the end by using one database user and I cannot manage physically for example logout after 15  minutes what is  your suggestion ?

Comment: @ZiadAdnan that's probably a whole new question really. The short answer is "yes" you can use database users to authenticate to an APEX application; however, the profile features will not work as you expect since APEX uses a db session pool.

Comment: ok If I use application users like users table can I make the user session logout after 10 minutes of idle time if I can what is the idea please ? thank you so much